# Which kind of python setup is more portable?

Tags: python, deployment, static-libraries, virtualenv, static-linking

I am wondering and pondering what python setup to use. Portable in sense of Portable Python in Windows (but i need such for Linux).

I am working on python project with a lot of dependencies , including C/C++ libraries , reuses some perl scripts , and even Java Tika lib to parse multiple document types. I want to put them all in local folder and bundle it so that they do not have to re-install when i am going to set it up on different servers (which have different Linux Distro , Gentoo , Ubuntu and Redhat ).

I wont use python provided by distro because it causes many headaches.

From studying around , these are choices I got :

1 - VirtualENV (But it defeat my purpose as it is not designed to relocate).

2 - Statically Compiling Python (Not sure how it will work, I do not see many success stories on it)

3 - Local (Manually) Compiling Python  (Wont work at different Libc version right?)

Any other choices ? Please let me know..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why this question is voted to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`virtualenv` is problematic, because it needs the libraries from the computer. Because nowadays most linux distros have python installed by default, the only case that'll be a problem is when the installed version on the computer is different than the one you're using.

However, I believe you can fix that by copying all the libs on `PYTHONPATH` that are placed on your local installation to the `virtualenv` folder.

I don't know about 2 or 3, but you could also try to [manually compile](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2) python to your USB disk and pip your libraries.

Comment: Thanks, i would like to know pitfalls of Custom compilations.

Comment: Now that I think of it every solution will depend on the target's architecture. No idea about special problems, however I never tried it myself.

Comment: Copying all the libs on python-path means the whole site-packages right?

Comment: I would try to avoid copying as much as you can and copy only libraries you cannot install using pip (eg standard library). You can find the virtualenv pip in bin/pip

Comment: Good , i am going to do manually local install and let you know.

Comment: If you interested , i have build my own python + many libaries runtime needed for my projects (python,numpy,scipy,scikit,matplotlib,java,perl,many others) it is totally relocatable and never need to rely on system libs except libc, tested on Ubuntu and Gentoo , works 100%! Reply me here if you need.